# Move window to another screen on_key_press

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm writing a simple image viewer and got to the point where I want to switch between displays.

I have a method that renders an image, inside there is:

```
 def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
            if symbol == key.S:
                if not self.msgbox_active:
                    self.msgbox_active = True

                    ret = int(choicebox(
                        msg='Choose screen to switch to',
                        title='Screen selection',
                        choices=[*range(1, len(self.screens) + 1)],
                    ))

                    if ret and ret - 1 != self.show_on :
                        self.show_on = ret - 1
                        self.window.set_fullscreen(True, screen=self.screens[self.show_on])

                    else:
                        self.msgbox_active = False
                    self.action = 'self'
```

I want to redraw a window, but due to fact that I need to initialize `pyglet.window.Window` earlier. When I `window.close()` and then initialize it over it complains about `pyglet.gl.ContextException: Unable to share contexts.`
My guess it's because there is one window already (although pyglet context documentation [states](https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/api/pyglet.gl.Context-class.html) that `each window has it's own context`.
Is there a way to update screen attribute of `Window` without (or with) recreating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move window to another screen we need:

```py
 self.window.set_fullscreen(True, screen=self.screens[self.show_on])
```

where `self.show_on` is number of screen to display image.